# constructor for inherited template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17

In the following code, I want to keep inheritance `class B : public A<F>`, but want to pass `globalFunction()` only to `A` and accessed from `B` as A::f1() and A::fa(). How can I do that?

```
#include <iostream>

void globalFunction()
{ }

//passing function to class A from main()
template<typename F>
class A
{
public:
    F f1;
    A(F fun1) : f1(fun1) {}
    void fa() {  f1();  } ;
};


template<typename F>
class B : public A<F>
{
public:
    B (F fun2) : A<F>(fun2) {}
    void fb() ; 
};

template<typename F>
void B<F>::fb() { A<F>::f1(); }

int main()
{
    A obja(globalFunction);
    obja.fa();
    B objb(globalFunction);
    objb.fb();
}
```

Basically I want to avoid making `B` as `B<F>`. Does inheriting `A<F>` to `B` makes `B` also a template `B<F>`? I am not using template argument `F` anywhere in `B`, it is just inherited from `A` and using from `B` as `A<F>::f1()`

User will pass function `globalFunction` to templated argument so,  `class B : public A<decltype(globalFunction)>` cannot be used.

Comment: You can make B a non-template only if it doesn't depend on template argument. For example, `class B : public A<decltype(global_function)>`. Otherwise it has to be a template for obvious reasons.

Comment: You *are* using the template argument `F` in `B`, to specify the class `A<F>` that it inherits from and the type of the constructor's parameter. (It does not inherit from `A`; `A` is not a class, it's a class template.)

Comment: You inherit from a template class, so obviously you depend on the arguments/types that base class template was instantiated from. There's no way to get away from that (nor should there be).

Comment: @SergeyA class definition is not accessible to user, so `global_function` from `class B : public A<decltype(global_function)>` is not known. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Why is `A` a template at all?

Comment: @molbdnilo function is passed to `A`, and it has some functions that need to access  passed functions

Comment: @ewr3243 if you know the type of function, and it is always a function, you can use a pointer to function instead of a template.

Comment: @SergeyA can put pointer to function implementation for this case in answer?

Comment: @ewr3243 done, answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that your functor type is always going to be a function of a certain signature, you can get rid of templates altogether:

```
void globalFunction()
{ }

//passing function to class A from main()

class A
{
public:
    using fptr_t = void (*)();
    fptr_t f1;
    A(fptr_t fun1) : f1(fun1) {}
    void fa() {  f1();  } ;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    B (fptr_t fun2) : A(fun2) {}
    void fb() ; 
};

void B::fb() { A::f1(); }

int main()
{
    A obja(globalFunction);
    obja.fa();
    B objb(globalFunction);
    objb.fb();
}
```

That is slightly detrimental to performance, since you would not be able to inline calls to your function pointers, but it does get rid of a template as requested.